# Many method on progress dialog cannot resolved

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, download, progressdialog

I create a program for downloading file with progress bar from URL server.

I use a reference from [Android Hive](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/)

But I have a modify this a little.

I use `extends Activity` on my class. and use doInBackground on AsyncTask.

This is for my onCreate code:

```
String TAG_NAME;
    String fileUrl;
    TextView teksDownload;

    Dialog pDialog;
    // Progress dialog type (0 - for Horizontal progress bar)
    public static final int progress_bar_type = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

        TAG_NAME= getIntent().getStringExtra("nama_file");

        fileUrl="http://myserver.com/"+TAG_NAME;

        teksDownload= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teksDownload);
        teksDownload.setText("Downloading "+fileUrl);

        new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(fileUrl);

    }
```

I use `protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)` and `class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>` Method. Approximately same code like this [Reference](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/).

And result, I Have 5 Error.

cannot find symbol method `setMessage(String)`, `setIndeterminate(boolean)`, `setMax(int)`, `setProgressStyle(int)`, `setProgress(int)`.

on this code:

```
case progress_bar_type:
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Downloading file. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setMax(100);
                pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
                return pDialog;
```

and this code:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            // setting progress percentage
            pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
        }
```

Comment: You've declared `pDialog` as a regular `Dialog`, which doesn't have those methods. Change the declaration to `ProgressDialog pDialog;`.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you very much, Why you answer it on comment? I can't mark or accept it as a right answer if your answer it on this comment.

Comment: I was looking for a duplicate. I was pretty sure I'd seen this asked before, but I can't find it. You can just accept Pawneshwer Gupta's answer, if you like. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your referenced link again.
he used `private ProgressDialog pDialog;` but you are using `Dialog`.

`Dialog` doesn't have those methods.